# How to apply various styles on a Widget depending of some variables?

Tags: java, eclipse, widget, styles, swt

I want to apply horizontal scroll in a Text widget depending of a variable.

I did it this way:

```
    int style = (SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.CANCEL | SWT.MULTI);

    if (!editable) {
        style = (style | SWT.READ_ONLY);
    }

    if (horizontalScroll) {
        style = (style | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    }

    text = new Text(composite, style);
```

The problem is that horizontal scroll is always present even when horizontalScroll boolean is false. Is not the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWT.CANCEL is not a style supported by the SWT Text widget.

You are unlucky in this case because SWT.CANCEL value equals SWT.H_SCROLL so by adding cancel style you are actually adding the horizontal scroll.

Styles supported by SWT Text Widget: CENTER, ICON_CANCEL, ICON_SEARCH, LEFT, MULTI, PASSWORD, SEARCH, SINGLE, RIGHT, READ_ONLY, WRAP.

Styles supported by inheritance: H_SCROLL, V_SCROLL, BORDER, LEFT_TO_RIGHT, RIGHT_TO_LEFT, FLIP_TEXT_DIRECTION

And you should check that there are some rules that some styles can't go together (ex SWT.SINGLE with SWT.MULTI).

Comment: thank you, then @BogdanAdrian102 this is the correct way to do it? creating an Integer and doing " | " with more values?

Comment: Yes, this is how I use them. " | " is a the binary OR operator that copies the bit if it exist in either operand. If you check the style's integer base 10 values they are all powers of 2 ( 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32,  ... ) which means that their base 2 representation contains only one value bit (00000001, 00000010, 00000100 ...).